# Number of parts equal to $~1~$ in all compositions of $~n~$

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let An be the total number parts that are equal to $~1~$ in all compositions of $~n~$. So $~A_1 = 1,~ A_2 = 2, ~A_3 = 5~,$ and $~A_4 = 12~$.

Prove that for
all $~n ≥ 2~$, the recurrence relation $$A_{n+1} = 2A_n + {2^n}^{-2} $$ holds.

My work:
I tried the following: take one composition of $n$ and fix one term, say $a_i$ . If $a_i$ = 1, subtract it. Then the number of $1$'s in composition of $n$ is $A_n$. I'm not sure where $2A_n$ is coming from. Also, we have many choices to pick $i$-th term.

For the term $2^{n-2}$, I was thinking that we can add $1$ anywhere to the the composition of $n$. But that is the furthest I got. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is sequence A045623 in OEIS (https://oeis.org/A045623).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compositions of $n+1$ fall into two classes:

- Compositions beginning with a $1$. There are $2^{n-1}$ such compositions, each beginning with a $1$, so we start with $2^{n-1}$ ones. The number of ones in the remaining parts is $A_n$, so the contribution from this case is $2^{n-1}+A_n$.
- Compositions beginning with some number $k>1$. There are again $2^{n-1}$ such compositions (why?). Imagine taking the set of all such compositions and replacing each initial $k$ with $k-1$. The resulting set is the set of all compositions of $n$, so it seems like there should still be $A_n$ ones among these compositions. However, if $k=2$, then the transformation $k\to (k-1)$ created an extra one. The number of extra ones created is the number of compositions of $n+1$ starting with $2$, which is $2^{n-2}$. We must subtract these out, so the contribution from this case is $A_n-2^{n-2}$.

Adding these two contributions together, we get $A_{n+1}=2A_n+2^{n-2}$.

---

Perhaps a more direct method; by considering all possibilities for the first part of the composition of $n+1$, we get the recurrence
$$
A_{n+1}=(2^{n-1}+A_n)+A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}+\dots+A_1
$$
Similarly, 
$$
A_n=(2^{n-2}+A_{n-1})+A_{n-2}+\dots+A_1
$$
Subtracting the two equations, you get
$$
A_{n+1}-A_n=(2^{n-1}-2^{n-2})+A_n
$$
which rearranges to what you want.

Comment: Thank you, still for the cases k=1 and k>0, why do we have compositions $2^{n-1}$ and not $2^{n- 2}$ and $2^{n-k}$?

Comment: When $k=1$, we have to delete some ones to transform the compositions of $(n+1)$ to compositions of $n$, so these $2^{n-1}$ ones need to be added to $A_n$. When $k=2$, we create some ones when we decrease $k$ to $k-1$, so these need to be subtracted from $A_n$. For all other $k$, there is no need to add/subtract any powers of $2$; we decrease $k$ to $k-1$, which does not create or destroy any ones, so all the ones in these transformed compositions are accounted for by $A_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: condition on the value $k$ of the first part:
$$A_{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} ([k=1]2^{n-1}+A_{n+1-k})$$