# explicit formula for the sum of the first part of all compositions of n

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let $s_n$ be the sum of the first part of all compositions of n. So $s_1$ = 1,
$s_2$ = 3, and $s_3$ = 7. Find an explicit formula for $s_n$.

I came up with the following solution and was wondering whether it is correct:

Let i be the first part of a composition. Let $ 1 \leq i \leq n-1 $. Number of times i appears as a first part of the other compositions is the number of compositions of $(n-i) = 2^{n-i-1}$. Then sum of all first terms is a sum over all $i$  multiplied by the $i$ value and value of n itself (not included in the sum):
$$s_n = n+ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i  \ 2^{n-i-1} $$

Is my solution correct or am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should give a link to your previous question on the same subject asked one hour before : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3531833

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this argument is correct, and this sum simplifies to $2^n-1$.  It might be cleaner to start the sum at $i=1$ instead of $i=0$.